# How to build with a default flavor dimension?

Tags: android, gradle

Having these flavors defined:

```
flavorDimensions "env", "type"

    productFlavors {
        new{
            dimension "type"
            ...
        }
        legacy{
            dimension "type"
            ...
        }
        staging {
            dimension "env"
            ...
        }
        prod {
            dimension "env"
            ...
        }
```

Is it possible in some way ask gradle to "assembleStaging" assuming that the default "type" dimension is "legacy"?

Comment: staging is a flavor and legacy is a flavor. You can't build two flavors together. Do I misunderstand the question? Perhaps you want to have **build types** of `staging` and `prod` then combine that with **flavors** of `new` and `legacy`? Then you could run `assembleStagingLegacy`

Comment: Actually you can build two flavors together by using different dimension. The problem here is that I want to use both "assembleLegacyStaging" and "assembleStaging"; but it seems it is not possible

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and I resolved it by using like this

```
flavorDimensions "type"

productFlavors {
    new{
        dimension "type"
        ...
    }
    legacy{
        dimension "type"
        ...
    }
    staging {
        dimension "type"
        ...
    }
    prod {
        dimension "type"
        ...
    }
```

You have to pass same dimension for each flavors.

When you write code in your main directory it'll common for all your flavors, you can write flavors related code in flavors directory.
For creating specific flavors debug build you can change it from Build Variants option at left bottom corner, for creating release build their is option appears for target flavors after entering your jks signing related details.

Comment: Yes it works like that! But I need to have both possibilities:
-assembleLegacyStaging
-assembleStaging

It's mainly because mine is an hybrid app and I need to have at least a flavor name identical to iOS build scheme counterpart